# How to get data from MS Word forms

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have .doc file that is protected from filling and it is only allowed to fill forms inside doc. File contains dropdown lists, checkboxes and textboxes. When I try to get text from file dropdown lists and checkboxes, they sends me “???” instead of any text.

How can I get text from these forms in C#.

This is how I get text:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object path = @"C:\DOC\myDocument.docx";
object readOnly = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
string totaltext = "";
for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
     totaltext += " \r\n "+ docs.Paragraphs[i+1].Range.Text.ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine(totaltext);
docs.Close();
word.Quit()
```

Comment: Please show us the code you use to get the text. Are there FormFields or ContentControls (with .doc, I suppose the first?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= docs.FormFields.Count; i++) 
{ 
    totaltext += " \r\n "+ docs.FormFields[i].Result.ToString();
}
```